# HttpContext User has 0 Claims, when using external google login

Tags: c#, authentication, identity

I am trying to set up Google external login on .Net Core web API with AspNetCore identity. However when I login with the google account, the claims in the HttpContext stay zero. I do not get any claims there.

Starutp.cs configuration:

```cs
services.Configure < CookiePolicyOptions > (options = >{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context = >true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
});

services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddGoogle("Google", g = >{
    g.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    g.ClientId = "";
    g.ClientSecret = "";
});

services.AddIdentity < ApplicationUser,
IdentityRole > ().AddEntityFrameworkStores < Context > ().AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options = >options.LoginPath = "/account/google");

var dbConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString");

services.AddDbContext < Context > (options = >options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(dbConnectionString));
```

AccountController

```cs
// Authorize is a problem cuz this.User has no claims
//[Authorize]
[HttpGet("loginCallback")]
public async Task < IActionResult > LoginCallback(string returnUrl) {
    //The add method here takes the claim arr from the context and maps it to a ApplicationUser
    await this.userService.Add();
    return Redirect("http://localhost:4200/");
}

[HttpGet("google")]
public IActionResult Google() {
    string returnUrl = HttpContext.Request.Query["ReturnUrl"];
    var callbackUrl = Url.Action("LoginCallback", "Account", new {
        returnUrl
    });
    returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? "/": returnUrl;

    return Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties() {
        RedirectUri = callbackUrl
    },
    "Google");
}
```